# Change background color of label when input radio is checked

Tags: html, css

I have a label wrapping an input radio button, what I want is that when the user clicks on the input radio, the label wrapping the radio changes its background color. How can I achieve that?

```css
.radio-label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.radio-label:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: var(--black);
}

.radio-label input {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

.radio-label input:checked .radio-label {
  background-color: var(--orange);
  color: var(--black);
}
```

```html
<label className="radio-label">
        <span>Test</span>
          <input    type="radio" name="test" id="test1" />
   </label>
```

Comment: You will have to put the input first and the label after it. Then you can use one of the sibling combinators (~ or +) to select the input.

Comment: There is the `:has()` pseudo class, but browser support isn't very great . You could do `label:has(input:checked)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is you are trying get radio label in the checked input with,
`.radio-label input:checked .radio-label`

If you change it from

```css
.radio-label input:checked .radio-label {
  background-color: var(--orange);
  color: var(--black);
}
```

to

```css
.radio-label:has(> input:checked) {
  background-color: var(--orange);
  color: var(--black);
}
```

It's should work for your case.

Note: This feature has not support on some spesific browser, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has)

Comment: Verified that this works with OPs markup +1

Answer (score 0):

You don't Have To wrap your input inside the `<label>` & Labels can also have text in them.no need to add a span inside aswell.

```css
.radio-label {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.radio-label:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: var(--black);
}

#test1 {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

#test1:checked~.radio-label {
  background-color: orange;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test1" />
<label for="test1" class="radio-label">Test</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.radio-label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
}

.radio-label:hover {
  background-color: #e5e5e5;
  color: var(--black);
}

.radio-label input {
  height: 1rem;
  width: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
}

input[type=radio]:checked+label {
    background-color: orange;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="test" id="test1" />
<label class="radio-label">Test</label>
```